# Can I remove Firebase observer with handle, using just the root reference?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have all the observers in a custom 'database' class that has a few functions and protocols that observe the references and pass the results through a closure. Because of that, I don't need a Firebase reference in some of my view controllers, just an instance of the class.
So my question is, does removing an observer with handle requite a specific reference?

Or can I just do 
`FIRDatabase.database().reference().removeObserver(withHandle: handle)` 
(maybe with some specific user's path in there), to remove the observer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unfortunately, you need to remove it on the same node where it was added. Keep in mind that you could add a handler on several node locations, even more than once per location, so this makes some sense.

Note that you can call [removeAllObservers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/ios/firebasedatabase/api/reference/Classes/FIRDatabaseReference#-removeallobservers) to remove any reference, without using the handle, but again, this only affects the specific path and is not recursively applied to child paths.

Comment: So does this mean that if I observer the same reference in multiple places, it would also remove _all_ the observers? Or is reference + handle a unique thing? Not that it really matters for me, I want to have just one observer at a time, I'm just curious :)

Comment: Every time you register an observer, you get back a unique handle. So you should call the each location with the correct handle for the listener at that location.